# Ubuntu won't boot since upgrading to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bootloader

I'm new to Ubuntu so be kind!

I recently installed 13.xx, some months ago. For the most part, there were only a few niggles and I was using Ubuntu fine.

Recently, though, I was asked into an automatic update to 14.04 - since I upgraded, I have developed my problem.

I was asked to restart now or later following an update and chose later, only for the screen to go black. When I try to turn the computer back on, I am now faced with the following screen (apologies for the grandma way of presenting ... I know taking photos of a screen is a cardinal sin!):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cmWk1PEh.jpg]

I read in another thread to press <kbd>e</kbd> on this screen, which results in this screen:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QENcyadh.jpg]

I also read that I should then change the `ro` in one of the lines to `rw` and press <kbd>F10</kbd>. I did this but the screen just goes to purple and does not change.

Am I doing everything wrong?

Thanks for reading and helping out an oldie (but a Linux newbie!) :-)

Comment: Those are shots of the grub menu where you select an OS to boot. use the arrow keys and select the top of the list under ubuntu and hit enter.

Comment: Hi bodhi - when I do that, it just goes to a purple screen. I have six options (3 normal and 3 recovery versions) on the "Ubuntu" menu.

Comment: Choose the top normal boot

Comment: When i do, I just get the following screen: http://i.imgur.com/5eV7DRRh.jpg

Comment: OK, well first boot a live 14.04 USB, If that works, do a fresh install. Your data in /home will be preserved. If it does not work see - http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Although you do not get a black screen, same solution.

Comment: What exactly does a love 14.04 USB boot mean?

Comment: make a live CD or usb (usb are more popular these days) and boot it.

Comment: Hi there - I have tried to do a new install, but I have encountered a problem. I have made a bootable USB drive using Universal USB Installer, using 14.04 64bit desktop version. When I go to install, I stumble at the point right after connecting to the internet - I get the following message: "Input/output error during read on /dev/sda". I can't get past this error message. Have I downloaded the wrong version? Thanks again guys!

Comment: Check the md5sum on the iso you downloaded

Comment: What exactly is an md5sum?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Answer (score 0):

I see what your problem is. You are pressing <kbd>e</kbd> when it comes up with the grub boot loader (that screen that you took a photo of). The key <kbd>e</kbd> is to edit the commands to forward to the Operating System when it boots. Based of of the information provided to me, it seems like you need to press the <kbd>enter / return</kbd> key instead. If it still will not boot, [try a fresh install of it.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)

Comment: Hi there - the screen just goes purple and does nothing at the GRUB stage. I have tried to do a new install, but I have encountered a problem. I have made a bootable USB drive using Universal USB Installer, using 14.04 64bit desktop version. When I go to install, I stumble at the point right after connecting to the internet - I get the following message: "Input/output error during read on /dev/sda". I can't get past this error message. Have I downloaded the wrong version? Thanks again guys!

Comment: is your computer a 64 or 32 bit computer? it should say on the front